# Error : The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found

Tags: wso2, esb

I got the following error.
Anyone help me to out.

org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /services/echo and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase.checkPostConditions(DispatchPhase.java:102)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:329)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.invokeAxisEngine(RESTUtil.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.processURLRequest(RESTUtil.java:139)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet$RestRequestProcessor.processURLRequest(AxisServlet.java:837)

Comment: This is a very common error and the message itself says what's wrong. How are you invoking the service?

Comment: i am invoking the service from the soap client(javax). But i couldnt know the exact error ? can you tell me exactly ?

Comment: Please try from SoapUI and see

Answer (score 2):

Resolved above issue by setting `SOAPAction` header with the appropriate action which is found using the WSDL and changing the content-type from `application/xml` to `text/xml` as I was using an HTTP client to send the SOAP request.

Sample request:

```
POST /services/HandlerProxy HTTP/1.1
content-type: text/xml
SOAPAction: urn:mediate
host: example.com:9080
user-agent: myClient
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 1251
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the right soapAction, currently your action is NULL.  Basically this error tells you that the combination of endpoint and action is not known on the ESB.

If you checkout the WSDL of the echo service you will see there are multiple operations possible. For example "urn:echoInt"